# Firebase storage downloadURL partial apply forwarder for @nonobjc message

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am testing a upload image to Firebase storage, but i got the message:

```
partial apply forwarder for @nonobjc  at xxxViewController.swift
```

Here is the code:

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
storage.reference().child("abc").putData(d, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
    guard let metadata = metadata else {
         print("error")
         return
    }
    let downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL
    print(downloadURL)
}
```

The output is just `(Function)` and with the message above.

Comment: Please add the metadata for data you sending in the Firebase

Comment: Hi you can try this https://github.com/shaharukhs/FirebaseUploadImageSwift or just copy [firebaseservices](https://github.com/shaharukhs/FirebaseUploadImageSwift/tree/master/fireBaseUploadImage/Model/FireBaseServices) to your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at it I am here uploading a profile image to firebase storage

```
if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image!) {

                storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                    if let error = error
                    {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //get download url if upload is successful 
                        let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                        print(downloadURL!)

                    }
                })
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/png"


let storage = Storage.storage()
storage.reference().child("abc").putData(d, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
    guard let metadata = metadata else {
         print("error")
         return
    }
    let downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL
    print(downloadURL)
}
```

This will solves your problem